# How to diagnose an unknown apache setup?

Tags: apache

I've been using mamp for a while now and everything has been working great. Then today I go to start it up and mamp alert tells me that apache is already running on that port and to pick another one. So without starting mamp, I type in local host in the web browser - my usual way to get to the sites that I'm developing - and a page pops up and it reads IT WORKS!, which tells me that I have an index.php file somewhere on my computer that echos It works!. But mamp is not running and I can't find this stupid it works file anywhere. Is there any way to diagnose this and perhaps kill this apache server so that I can start mamp back up without switching my ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mamp is the only server you're running locally, you might want to try opening activity monitor, look for all running myslqld processes and quit them, then restart Mamp

or, as asked, through the terminal: killall -9 mysqld

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsof` to find out which processes are listening on which ports.

For example:

```
lsof -Pnl +M -i4 | grep ":80"
```

(assuming the process is running on port 80)

You can then use `ps` to figure out the name of the process for that processID:

```
ps -p <pid>
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. Is there any way to then somehow kill that connection from the terminal?

Comment: Thanks, that not only helped me with my previous problem, it also helped figure out how to kill this stupid carbonite process (annoying pop-up that wouldn't go away).